# Java class and subclass

Tags: java, class, inheritance

I'm learning now Java classes.

I have class Person. From Person I have 2 subclasses `Father` and `Mother`.
One Father can have 3 Children ( Child 1, Child 2, Child 3).
Now I want co access the father of a child. How could I do that?

My current code:

class Person

```
public class Person {
    String name;
    int age;
    String addresse;

    public Person (){
    }

    public Person(String name, int age, String addresse) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.addresse = addresse;
    }
}
```

class Father

```
public class Father extends Person {
  
    Person child1;
    Person child2;
    Person child3;    

    public Father() {
    }

    public Father(String name, int age, String addresse) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.addresse = addresse;
    }

    public void setName(Name name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

My main.java.
I create a Father and one Person and assign it to child 1.

```
public class PersonTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Father f = new Father();
        f.setName("Joe");

        Person p1 = new Person();
        p1.setName("Kai")

        f.child1 = p1;
    }
}
```

Now i.e I want to get the Father's name of child1 through p1. How could I do that?

Comment: You can't. A `Person` does not know if it has a father and what that father would be.

Comment: Lets assume you have two Father objects `Father f1 = new Father();` `Father f2 = new Father();`. Now comes strange but *possible* thing: you assign *same* Child object to *both Father objects*, like `Person ch = new Person();` `f1.child1 = ch; f2.child1 = ch;`. Which of those fathers would you like to get? Compiler doesn't know your intentions, so it is up to you to provide some *mechanism* which will work according to it.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a bidirectional dependency between the child and the father. If this is a good design decision - is not part of my answer.

```
public class Person {
    String name;
    int age;
    String addresse;
    Father father;

    public Person (){
    }

    public Person(String name, int age, String addresse) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.addresse = addresse;
    }

    public void setFather(Father father) { 
        this.father = father;
    }
}
```

Create a setter which does the bidirectional linking:

```
public class Father extends Person {
  
    Person child1;
    Person child2;
    Person child3;    

    public Father() {
    }

    public Father(String name, int age, String addresse) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.addresse = addresse;
    }

    public void setName(Name name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
    public void setChild1(Person child1) {
        this.child1 = child1;
        this.child1.setFather(this);
    }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
public class PersonTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Father f = new Father();
        f.setName("Joe");

        Person p1 = new Person();
        p1.setName("Kai")

        f.setChild1(p1);
 
        // p1.father
    }
}
```